How to know server timezone
Is there any way to pass Apache Nifi server timezone into Processors?
For example, in UpdateRecord I tried the following expression:
${Duser.timezone}

also:
#{-Duser.timezone}

But it does not return anything

can't check right now but i'm sure this should work ${user.timezone}
D is not a part of system property name.

according to
https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/expression-language-guide.html#usage
system properties are available in nifi expression language
